# Write an extension to vpn firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, vpn

Scenario: I want to write a **Firefox extension** which **connects to a pre-defined VPN** only for certain URLs. For example, if I type "drama.myinstitute.edu", it connects to the VPN of my institute and gets the required webpage, given that the webpage is not available outside the subnet of my institute.

There are extensions like AnonynmX and Zenmate which *claim* to **connect to a pre-defined VPN** with the aim of hiding behind a proxy.

Though I am fairly comfortable with JS, I haven't ever written a Firefox extension and have no idea where to start. The basic documentation covers interacting with content on various tabs, but hardly anything for the lower layer of networking.

If anyone can provide me a **hint** of **where to start**, I will be thankful.